# Microsoft.Bot.Builder - sporadic error - "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'"

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm developing a chatbot using Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3.15.2.2, [QnA Maker](https://www.qnamaker.ai/old) (preview mode, aka 'old') and [QnAMakerDialog](https://github.com/garypretty/botframework/tree/master/QnAMakerDialog) (from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices v1.1.7). I'm using Direct API as a channel and [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) to embed my chatbox in a web page. I've also implemented a custom bot data store to persist the bot's state.

From time to time (I cannot establish a pattern), during a conversation with the bot, I receive the following error:

```
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 
'Unauthorized' at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.
<ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__9.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous 
location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.
ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.
HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.
ConversationsExtensions.<ReplyToActivityAsync>d__9.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from 
previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.
TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at UCB.ChatBot.Bot.Controllers.MessagesController.<Post>d__3.
MoveNext() in [...]Bot\Controllers\MessagesController.cs:line 39
```

After this error shows up, the bot keeps replying 'Sorry! Not able to match any of the options.' or, keeps giving you an answer to a question asked way before, in the beginning of the conversation. A Ctrl + F5 fixes this issue and the bot returns to the expected behavior.

This happens sporadically - as I said, I cannot establish a pattern or reproduce it. Maybe once or twice a day or a week.

Any thoughts or hints are very welcomed.

Comment: Hi Diana, this is a known issue with the SDK we are actively working on a fix for. The next package we release should have a fix for this, no ETA at this time.

Comment: Jason, thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 4):

We have released a new package  [3.15.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/3.15.2.3) that we believe addresses this issue.  Please let us know if you are still experiencing this issue after upgrading by commenting in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4733) on the botbuilder repository

Comment: Thank you, Jason, for letting me know! I have that proiect on hold now, but as soon as I have the chance I'll try the new package.